# Creating and using multi-table join table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord

I have 3 tables, Users, Roles and Companies. A user can have multiple roles, without being part of a company. However, if a user is part of a company, their associated roles inside the company should be defined.

To this end, I have created tables:

- roles_users (joins role and user tables)
- companies_users (joins the 3 table)

The `companies_users` table has 3 columns, and a multicolumn unique prefix set.

```
create_table "companies_users", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "role_id",    null: false
  t.integer "company_id", null: false
  t.integer "user_id",    null: false
  t.index ["role_id", "company_id", "user_id"], name: "index_companies_users_on_role_id_and_company_id_and_user_id", unique: true
  t.index ["role_id"], name: "index_companies_users_on_role_id"
  t.index ["company_id"], name: "index_companies_users_on_startup_id"
  t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_companies_users_on_user_id"
end
```

I now have to create a form wherein, when a user signs up, can choose whether they want to provide their company details. In doing so, they'd also provide their role in those companies. The models are defined:

## User.rb

```
HABTM :company
HABTM :roles
accepts_nested_attributes_for :companies
accepts_nested_attributes_for :roles
```

## Company.rb

```
has_many :companies_users
has_many :roles, through: :companies_users
has_many :users, through: :companies_users
```

## Role.rb

```
HABTM :companies
HABTM :users
```

The models for join tables just define a `belongs_to` association. My form is created okay. It is sending the data as I desire:

```
{
  "utf8": "✓",
  "authenticity_token": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "user": {
    "first_name": "My",
    "last_name": "Name",
    "location": "and location",
    "role_ids": [
      "2"
    ],
    "companies_attributes": {
      "0": {
        "name": "Company",
        "founding_year": "2017",
        "location": "Earth",
        "facebook": "facebook",
        "linkedin": "linkedin",
        "website": "website",
        "logo": "logo",
        "revenue_rate": "20",
        "private": "1",
        "role_ids": [
          "5", "8"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "commit": "Update User"
}
```

and this fails, because rails tries to create a row as follows:

```
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "companies" ("name", "location", "founding_year", "website", "facebook", "linkedin", "revenue_rate", "created_at", "updated_at", "logo") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["name", "Company"], ["location", "Earth"], ["founding_year", 2017], ["website", "website"], ["facebook", "facebook"], ["linkedin", "linkedin"], ["revenue_rate", 20], ["created_at", 2017-06-18 05:08:16 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-06-18 05:08:16 UTC], ["logo", "logo"]]
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "companies_users" ("role_id", "company_id") VALUES (?, ?)  [["role_id", 5], ["company_id", 122]]
   (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
```

How do I handle a 3-way join table successfully?

---

### EDIT

The controller simply has the following code:

```
  def finish_signup
    if request.patch? and params[:user] #&& params[:user][:email]
      if @user.update(user_params)
        redirect_to root_path
      else
        @show_errors = true
      end
    end

    if request.get?
      @user = current_user
      @company = @user.companies.build
      @role = @user.roles.build
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you show the controller code that is handling the update?

Comment: @MichaelGorman Updated

Comment: the user should `has_many :companies_users`, and `have_many :companies, through: :companies_users`

Comment: @MichaelGorman Doesn't HABTM (`has and belongs to many`) do that?

Comment: yes but it assumes the association table isn't a ruby model, just a double foreign key table.  In your case the table is a triple foreign key table, which doesn't fit the Rails HABTM standard

Comment: @MichaelGorman Tried that. No effect, it is still inserting the relations in 2's.